# Binding plain JSON to jgGRID

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I am pretty new to jqGrid. Could someone guide me where i am going wrong in binding JSON to jqGrid?
Please note – i dont any control over web service so cannot modify json sent from web service.
Your help will be greatly appreciated.

**JSON format:**

```
    [{"DepositType":0,"DepositId":0,"ReceiptNumber":"","CompanyId":2," Company":"Cosmos cooperative ","EmployeeId":1," EmployeeName ":"Abhilash Shah","MaturityDate":"2012-08-11T00:00:00","MaturityAmount":23311.0,"DateInvested":"2011-03-05T00:00:00","AmountInvested":20000.0,"ROI":10.25,"Term":16," ","IsWithdrawn":false,"Purpose":"","Comments":""},
    {"DepositType":1,"DepositId":0,"ReceiptNumber":"9993","CompanyId":1,"Company":" Janta Sahakari Ltd","EmployeeId":3,"EmployeeName":"Sheela Shah","MaturityDate":"2013-06-11T00:00:00","MaturityAmount":253644.0,"DateInvested":"2012-06-11T00:00:00","AmountInvested":0.0,"ROI":0.0,"Term":12," ","IsWithdrawn":false,"Purpose":"","Comments":""},
    {"DepositType":0,"DepositId":0,"ReceiptNumber":"","CompanyId":1,"Company":"Solapur Janta Sahakari  Ltd","EmployeeId":3,"EmployeeName":"Sheela Shah","MaturityDate":"2013-08-30T00:00:00","MaturityAmount":125161.0,"DateInvested":"2011-05-30T00:00:00","AmountInvested":100000.0,"ROI":10.1,"Term":27, "IsWithdrawn":false,"Purpose":"","Comments":""},
    {"DepositType":0,"DepositId":0,"ReceiptNumber":"226575","CompanyId":6,"Company":" of Maharashtra","EmployeeId":3,"EmployeeName":"Sheela Shah","MaturityDate":"2013-10-05T00:00:00","MaturityAmount":100000.0,"DateInvested":"2012-10-05T00:00:00","AmountInvested":100000.0,"ROI":10.05,"Term":12, "IsWithdrawn":false,"Purpose":"","Comments":""}
    ]
```

**Below is the code snippet:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#depositGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'http://localhost:50570/api/com…..s&#39;,
                datatype: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            colNames: ['ID','Employee Name'],
            colModel: [{ name: 'ID', width: 1, hidden: true, key: true },
            { name: 'EmployeeName', index: ' EmployeeName ', align: "center", sortable: true }          ],
            autowidth: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'ReceiptNumber',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            caption: 'My first grid',
            editurl:"",                                               
            imgpath: 'themes/basic/images'

        });

     });
    </script>
    <div id="jqgrid">
        <table id="depositGrid"></table>
        <div id="Pager"></div>
    </div>
```

I am not sure what's wrong with above binding. Please guide me.

Regards,

Abhilash

Comment: I don't get any error, however the grid is empty, no data is displayed. My concern is- Default format expected is below for jqGrid however the format that i provide doesnt match:
{ 
  total: "xxx", 
  page: "yyy", 
  records: "zzz",
  rows : [
    {id:"1", cell:["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {id:"2", cell:["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
      ...
  ]
} 
How do map JSON i mentioned in original post to jgGrid required format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked with JSON reader as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery("#west-grid").jqGrid({
            url: 'http://localhost:50570/api/common/GetElapsedDeposits',
            mtype: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            jsonReader: {
                root: function (obj) { return obj; },
                page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.length; },
                id: "0",
                cell: "",
                repeatitems: false
            },
            datatype: "json",
            height: 250,
            colNames: ['Employee Name'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'EmployeeName', index: ' EmployeeName ', align: "center", sortable: true }          ],
            autowidth: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            caption: 'My first grid'    
        });

     });
    </script>
    <div id="jqgrid">
        <table id="depositGrid"></table>
        <div id="Pager"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but in the jsonReader the id:0, I have never need this ... I think it try to bind the id to a field named "0".
And jqgrid will try to get the rows in (yourjson).rows

Jsonreader is optional ...

You can just remove this and set your index colum to the real data id ...

And in your column definition, you bind to a field ID and it's not present in your json ...

Exemple :

JSON:

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":2,"rows":[{"Id":458,"ArticleNo":null,"CUP":null,"Name":"test desc"},{"Id":459,"ArticleNo":null,"CUP":null,"Name":"qweqwe"}]}
```

Javascript:

```
 $('#Items').jqGrid({
    url: ItemsAjaxGetUrl,
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: [Res_Name, 'SKU', 'CUP', ''],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 300 },
        { name: 'SKU', index: 'ArticleNo', width: 120 },
        { name: 'CUP', index: 'CUP', width: 160 },
        { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 60, hidden: true, key: true }
    ],
    autowidth: true,
    rowNum: 25,
    rowList: [25, 50, 75, 100],
    pager: '#ItemsPager',
    sortname: 'Id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "asc",
    caption: ItemsContainer.attr('title'),
    editurl: "",
    hiddengrid: (ItemsContainer.data("hidden") === 'true'),
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        if (id && id !== ItemsLastSel) {
            ItemsSelectedRowId = id;
            $('.actionBtnItems').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        if (!id) {
            ItemsSelectedRowId = null;
            $('.actionBtnItems').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Benoit, however no luck. Updated the jqGrid as per your suggestion (Update in original post as well - remvoed jsonReader). Still data is not displayed. Any clue what is going wrong?

Comment: If you declare column a, b, c; json will look like : rows = [{a: 'value a', b: 'value b', c: 'value c'},{ a: 'value a', b: 'value b', c: 'value c' }]  did you read this? http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: Try with 1 or 2 column with same name in your json response to see if its a binding error ... like I sait, I suspect your ID column to be missing, just remove it to see ...

Comment: Ya, i am reading it via URL property set in jqGrid declaration.
Are you sure we dont need jsonreader in this case -
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data says 
"**jsonReader as Function**
In certain situation you will obtain the data from a web service. In this case it is not possible to configure all the properties of the response so that the grid will work properly."

Comment: All column must be in your json response ... if you specify a column id and its not in the json, no data will be displayed ...

Comment: I have no Id column in my JSON, so removed it from jsonreader. Removed jsonreader too as per your suggestion. I am now only binding EmployeeName, however no luck.
I have check other resources, and the format jgGrid expects for JSON is different than what I am providing. Please see format in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412818/jggrid-will-not-load-json-data
Format I am providing is different. Do you see any issue there?

Comment: it look good ... im using the paging fonctionality, my json result look like this : {"total":1,"page":1,"records":2,"rows":[{"Id":458,"ArticleNo":null,"CUP":null,"Name":"test desc"},{"Id":459,"ArticleNo":null,"CUP":null,"Name":"qweqwe"}]}

but with something like this it's supposed to work : [{"Id":458,"ArticleNo":null,"CUP":null,"Name":"test desc"},{"Id":459,"ArticleNo":null,"CUP":null,"Name":"qweqwe"}]

Comment: Thanks but this too dint work. Please find my post updated with latest jgGrid code as per your suggestion to have dummy ID column.
However I am not sure what you meant by - "You can just remove this and set your index colum to the real data id ..."
Can you please review my code and let me know if you see anything missing or want me to modify anything? Many thanks!

Comment: Remove id : colNames: ['Employee Name'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'EmployeeName', index: ' EmployeeName ', align: "center", sortable: true }          ]

Answer (score 0):

The first two elements in the data array doesn't follow json format. It has got a `""` after the `"Term"` property. Also there is a `" EmployeeName "` in the first element which I guess is a typo.

Try with the following data and it should work. It worked for me.

```
[{"DepositType":0,"DepositId":0,"ReceiptNumber":"","CompanyId":2," Company":"Cosmos cooperative ","EmployeeId":1,"EmployeeName":"Abhilash Shah","MaturityDate":"2012-08-11T00:00:00","MaturityAmount":23311.0,"DateInvested":"2011-03-05T00:00:00","AmountInvested":20000.0,"ROI":10.25,"Term":16,"IsWithdrawn":false,"Purpose":"","Comments":""},
    {"DepositType":1,"DepositId":0,"ReceiptNumber":"9993","CompanyId":1,"Company":" Janta Sahakari Ltd","EmployeeId":3,"EmployeeName":"Sheela Shah","MaturityDate":"2013-06-11T00:00:00","MaturityAmount":253644.0,"DateInvested":"2012-06-11T00:00:00","AmountInvested":0.0,"ROI":0.0,"Term":12,"IsWithdrawn":false,"Purpose":"","Comments":""},
    {"DepositType":0,"DepositId":0,"ReceiptNumber":"","CompanyId":1,"Company":"Solapur Janta Sahakari  Ltd","EmployeeId":3,"EmployeeName":"Sheela Shah","MaturityDate":"2013-08-30T00:00:00","MaturityAmount":125161.0,"DateInvested":"2011-05-30T00:00:00","AmountInvested":100000.0,"ROI":10.1,"Term":27, "IsWithdrawn":false,"Purpose":"","Comments":""},
    {"DepositType":0,"DepositId":0,"ReceiptNumber":"226575","CompanyId":6,"Company":" of Maharashtra","EmployeeId":3,"EmployeeName":"Sheela Shah","MaturityDate":"2013-10-05T00:00:00","MaturityAmount":100000.0,"DateInvested":"2012-10-05T00:00:00","AmountInvested":100000.0,"ROI":10.05,"Term":12, "IsWithdrawn":false,"Purpose":"","Comments":""}
    ]
```

Comment: My bad. Both of the issues you mentioned in JSON were typo from my side. Sincere apology. 
I have tried but it didnt work until I provided details of JSON reader.